# Как запретить изменять размер BorderPane в JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

Как запретить изменять размер BorderPane в JavaFX? Параметр resizeble не активен. Везде установил нужные мне размеры(300,400), но при запуске все-равно создается окно меньшего размера, и его можно растягивать.

Comment: Запретить надо изменять размер окна

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо

1. Задать максимальный размер borderPane

`pane.setMaxSize(300, 400);
 pane.setPrefSize(300, 400);
 pane.setMinSize(300, 400);`

2. Запретить растягивать окно, в котором этот borderPane находится

`stage.setResizable(false);`

Answer (score 1):

Вам требуется менять размеры `Stage stage` стандартными методами:

```
stage.setMinWidth(w);
stage.setMinHeight(h);
stage.setWidth(w);
stage.setHeight(h);
stage.setMaxWidth(w);
stage.setMaxHeight(h);
```